# Nested IF function in excel not working

Tags: excel, if-statement

I am trying to implement an IF function for a simple pricing database where if a cell is equal to one of 3 time durations, the cell automatically generates the correct price based on length of time. Here's what I have so far based on what other examples have of nested Excel functions:

```
=IF(F4=12;"$60";IF(F4=6;"$40";IF(F4=3,"$30")))
```

My primary issue is that the second condition has a red bracket, indicating an error. If I then swap the ";" for a ",", I have the same result.

As there are only 3 conditions, I have also tried the following:

```
=IF(F4=12;"$60",IF(F4=6;"$40","$30")
```

But again I have the same issue with the bracket being red on the second condition.

Any ideas?

Comment: Just to be a little pedantic, this doesn't work for you either? `=IF(F4=12,"$60",IF(F4=6,"$40",IF(F4=3,"$30")))` (if not, try using `;` instead of `,`). I believe the language settings of the computer determine what the delimiter is. In the US, default is comma.

Comment: I'm not familiar with using semicolons in Excel functions, but I would suggest using all commas: `IF(F4=12,"$60",IF(F4=6,"$40",IF(F4=3,"$30")))`.  Either way, be consistent. I don't know why you are mixing commas and semicolons (`,` vs `;`).

Comment: Even if I use a comma, the bracket still becomes red and the condition cannot be used. The mixing was just an error on my part, I was either using all semi colons or all commas to see if the difference was in the formatting. I must have missed a comma or two when placing the question here.

For what it's worth, the example Excel gives when I start typing the formula uses semi colons.

Comment: Fixed it with exactly the same formula that didn't originally work.